# PHP Variables not displaying in Quiz/Assessment Results page

Tags: php, wordpress, variables

I have a quiz/questionnaire that I am trying to have print specific results after completion, depending on the score the person receives in 3 different categories. The scoring portion is working fine and has no issues, however the results are not being printed to the results page and I can't see what I am doing wrong.

I was trying to expand on the code a little to clean it up and make it easier to make adjustments to specific score ranges, but somewhere along the way it broke.  Here is the original code that was displaying properly on the results page.

Original Code that works perfectly (Same thing was for Blue/Red/Black):

```
if ($blueTotal >=0 && $blueTotal<=10){echo "<div id='results'> $blueTotal /  Here is what this means to you!</div>";}
else if ($blueTotal >=11 && $blueTotal<=20){echo "<div id='results'>$blueTotal /  Here is what his means to you!</div>";}
else if ($blueTotal >=21 && $blueTotal<=30){echo "<div id='results'>$blueTotal /  Here is what his means to you!</div>";}
else echo "<div id='results'>$blueTotal /  Here is what his means to you!</div>";
```

Here is the updated version where I am trying to add a few more steps for ease of adjustments later on with 30+ varieties. But now it does not print anything on the results page and just shows blank. What am I missing?

Update Part 1:

```
if ($blueTotal >=0 && $blueTotal<=10){$blueLow;}
else if ($blueTotal >=11 && $blueTotal<=22){$blueMedium;}
else if ($blueTotal >=23 && $blueTotal<=35){$blueHigh;}

if ($redTotal >=0 && $redTotal<=8){$redLow;}
else if ($redTotal >=9 && $redTotal<=15){$redMedium;}
else if ($redTotal >=16 && $redTotal<=25){$redHigh;}

if ($blackTotal >=0 && $blackTotal<=11){$blackLow;}
else if ($blackTotal >=12 && $blackTotal<=21){$blackMedium;}
else if ($blackTotal >=22 && $blackTotal<=34){$blackHigh;}
```

Update Part 2:

```
if ($blueLow && $redLow && $blackLow){echo $lowLowLow;}
else if ($blueLow && $redLow && $blackMedium){echo $lowLowMedium;}
else if ($blueLow && $redLow && $blackHigh){echo $lowLowHigh;}
```

Update Part 3:

```
$lowLowLow = 
"<div id='results'>$blueTotal / $redTotal / $blackTotal</div>
<div id='explanation'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce fringilla, turpis a ultricies ultricies, tellus nisi faucibus dui, ac lobortis.</div>";

$lowLowMedium = 
"<div id='results'>$blueTotal / $redTotal / $blackTotal</div>
<div id='explanation'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce fringilla, turpis a ultricies ultricies, tellus nisi faucibus dui, ac lobortis.</div>";

$lowLowHigh = 
"<div id='results'>$blueTotal / $redTotal / $blackTotal</div>
<div id='explanation'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce fringilla, turpis a ultricies ultricies, tellus nisi faucibus dui, ac lobortis.</div>";
```

Thanks in advance, any assistance appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? ```if ($blueTotal >=0 && $blueTotal<=10){$blueLow;}``` You don't echo the ```$blueLow``` variable, you don't define it, this line is useless now, so as lines below.

Comment: @Lothric I'm trying to make it so every time the score of blue falls between 0 - 10, it makes $blueLow. Then I want to define Blue low later on.

Comment: @Lothric Would It work if I defined the variables like this:

`$blueLow = ($blueTotal >=0 && $blueTotal<=10);`
`$blueMedium = ($blueTotal >=11 && $blueTotal<=22);`
`$blueHigh = ($blueTotal >=23 && $blueTotal<=35);`

Comment: Yes, that should work